# Complement Multiply With Carry (CMWC) RNG C winmain@16 compile issue

Tags: c, random, compilation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry#Complementary-multiply-with-carry_RNGs
has some code in C

I'm trying to compile it, but when I do I get this error
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1......\libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c|| undefined reference to `WinMain@16'|

Here's the code

I hope to figure out how to implement it and use it instead of booster's mersenne twister.

As someone pointed out, I was missing my main function, but now with it, I'm still having an issue getting it to run.

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define PHI 0x9e3779b9

static uint32_t Q[4096], c = 362436;



int main
{
    init_rand(6);

    int c = rand_cmwc();
};

void init_rand(uint32_t x)
{
        int i;

        Q[0] = x;
        Q[1] = x + PHI;
        Q[2] = x + PHI + PHI;

        for (i = 3; i < 4096; i++)
                Q[i] = Q[i - 3] ^ Q[i - 2] ^ PHI ^ i;
}

uint32_t rand_cmwc(void)
{
        uint64_t t, a = 18782LL;
        static uint32_t i = 4095;
        uint32_t x, r = 0xfffffffe;
        i = (i + 1) & 4095;
        t = a * Q[i] + c;
        c = (t >> 32);
        x = t + c;
        if (x < c) {
                x++;
                c++;
        }
        return (Q[i] = r - x);
}
```

Comment: Have you defined the `main()` function anywhere in your code? That's what the error is about, the compiler (linker, actually) is unable to find it to produce an executable program.

Comment: I just added the main function, but main doesn't like it when I put in anything, but I guess that's a start.  I probably need to include some more header files.

Comment: I think I found an answer, this code is implemented somewhere else http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftazemodz.net76.net%2Froot%2Fssyn.c&ei=BTx7UNuaLqHKigK8_ICABQ&usg=AFQjCNEtAsrJH9cZO3fcaBB1UHtYVt2lsQ&sig2=RofcspHpQdYKSQa-JVIkPw

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I figured it out.

I was missing my main function.

I then implemented the code as a class, in hopes to make it thread safe (allowing for multiple seeds)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


#define PHI 0x9e3779b9

using namespace std;

static uint32_t Q[4096], c = 362436;

class cmwc
{

  public:

    void init_rand(uint32_t x)
    {
        int i;

        Q[0] = x;
        Q[1] = x + PHI;
        Q[2] = x + PHI + PHI;

        for (i = 3; i < 4096; i++)
                Q[i] = Q[i - 3] ^ Q[i - 2] ^ PHI ^ i;
    }

    uint32_t rand_cmwc(void)
    {
        uint64_t t, a = 18782LL;
        static uint32_t i = 4095;
        uint32_t x, r = 0xfffffffe;
        i = (i + 1) & 4095;
        t = a * Q[i] + c;
        c = (t >> 32);
        x = t + c;
        if (x < c) {
                x++;
                c++;
        }
        return (Q[i] = r - x);
    }

    uint32_t random_num;

};

int main()
{
    cmwc rng1;

    rng1.init_rand(time(NULL));

    rng1.random_num = 1 + rng1.rand_cmwc()%6;

    //int r = rng1.rand_cmwc();

    cout << "die: " << rng1.random_num << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to your question. Please add the new info (not just the code, but also some explanation of how it helps with your problem, if at all) to the question and delete this "answer".

Comment: well, it's answered now.  The problem was not having the main function, I got it to work by recreating a source file from scratch, and then I saw how the methods were to be used.  I guess more specifically, the instructions on how to use it are in the main function.

Comment: Great! But you shouldn't be mixing C and C++.

Comment: I'm a newb, I know there compatible, is it the uint32_t types that is showing me as a newb?

Comment: It's just awkward to `#include` `<stdio.h>` and not even `<cstdio>` and then `<iostream>` and use `std::cout`. :)

Comment: I didn't use std::cout... I never do that.  I used cout... but that's how I was taught c++ in school.  Well, they also taught me printf.  Oh, I get it... I'm old school.